# MVC3: update Model after adding two columns to the table

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Hi I have a few more questions on MVC3 Model and App_data.

1. I want to add two columns to my table, say lat, and lon. I can do that from sql script. 
   But after adding these two columns, how can I update the Model so the new columns will be the members of the Model?
2. I have a list of articles I want to display, what's the reliable way to display them in one view, instead of creating one view for each article?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What are you using for data access? Entity Framework? Code-first?

Comment: I would recommend separating this question into 2 questions.  With question 1, you will have to provide the model that needs to be updated and what it is exactly you are trying to achieve.  I'm not sure what question 2 is?  What does an article consist of?  I'm guessing you could display them in a table but without further information it is hard for anyone to answer.

Comment: oh, that was my first question. I am learning to post online. I will go check out the other question.

Comment: Here is the detail for Question #1. I have a Model that has a bunch of members like "name,address, type, grade" from the app_data/table. Now I want to add two new columns "lat", "lon" to the table. How could I update the model or connection to make it possible that I can refer to Model.lat, Model.lon in my Views? -- Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer to question 1:**

Simply update your view model to store the additional fields.  For example:

```
public class IndexModel
{
   //existing fields
   public string Name { get; set; }

   public string Address { get; set; }

   //etc

   //your new fields
   public string lat { get; set; } //use the preferred type

   public string lon { get; set; }
}
```

Then, in the controller action you can update the model with the new fields from the database using entity framework or however you choose to connect to the database.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult 
    {
        IndexModel model = //retrieve model from database here...
        return View(model);
    }
}
```